# Sequence Graph Transform - Error in Python SGT multiprocessing

Tags: python, jupyter, python-multiprocessing

I am using python3 in Jupyter under Anaonda distribution and using sgt package 2.0.3. System - 64bit 8GB. The SGT function worked fine when I did not use multiprocessing but it throws an error when I use multiprocessing. Could you please help me if there is any system dependency to use the multiprocessing functionality?

```
from sgt import SGT
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandarallel

corpus = pd.DataFrame([[1, ["B","B","A","C","A","C","A","A","B","A"]], 
                   [2, ["C", "Z", "Z", "Z", "D"]]], 
                  columns=['id', 'sequence'])
sgt = SGT(kappa=1, 
      flatten=True, 
      lengthsensitive=False, 
      mode='default')
sgt.fit_transform(corpus)
```

However, when I run mode='multiprocessing' it throws following error

```
sgt = SGT(kappa=1, 
      flatten=True, 
      lengthsensitive=False,
      mode='multiprocessing')
sgt.fit_transform(corpus)
```

Output:

```
 

    INFO: Pandarallel will run on 7 workers.
    INFO: Pandarallel will use standard multiprocessing data transfer (pipe) to transfer data between the main process and workers.

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
     in 
          3           lengthsensitive=False,
          4           mode='multiprocessing')
    ----> 5 sgt.fit_transform(corpus)

    ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sgt\sgt.py in fit_transform(self, corpus)
        214                                         list(self.fit(x['sequence'])),
        215                                         axis=1,
    --> 216                                         result_type='expand')
        217             sgt.columns = ['id'] + self.feature_names
        218             return sgt

    ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandarallel\pandarallel.py in closure(data, func, *args, **kwargs)
        440         try:
        441             pool = Pool(
    --> 442                 nb_workers, worker_init, (prepare_worker(use_memory_fs)(worker),),
        443             )
        444 

    ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py in Pool(self, processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild)
        117         from .pool import Pool
        118         return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild,
    --> 119                     context=self.get_context())
        120 
        121     def RawValue(self, typecode_or_type, *args):

    ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py in __init__(self, processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild, context)
        174         self._processes = processes
        175         self._pool = []
    --> 176         self._repopulate_pool()
        177 
        178         self._worker_handler = threading.Thread(

    ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py in _repopulate_pool(self)
        239             w.name = w.name.replace('Process', 'PoolWorker')
        240             w.daemon = True
    --> 241             w.start()
        242             util.debug('added worker')
        243 

    ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py in start(self)
        110                'daemonic processes are not allowed to have children'
        111         _cleanup()
    --> 112         self._popen = self._Popen(self)
        113         self._sentinel = self._popen.sentinel
        114         # Avoid a refcycle if the target function holds an indirect

    ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py in _Popen(process_obj)
        320         def _Popen(process_obj):
        321             from .popen_spawn_win32 import Popen
    --> 322             return Popen(process_obj)
        323 
        324     class SpawnContext(BaseContext):

    ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py in __init__(self, process_obj)
         87             try:
         88                 reduction.dump(prep_data, to_child)
    ---> 89                 reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
         90             finally:
         91                 set_spawning_popen(None)

    ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py in dump(obj, file, protocol)
         58 def dump(obj, file, protocol=None):
         59     '''Replacement for pickle.dump() using ForkingPickler.'''
    ---> 60     ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
         61 
         62 #

    AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'prepare_worker..closure..wrapper'
```

Comment: Best way to get an answer here is to create an issue at the github repo. https://github.com/cran2367/sgt/issues

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly due to the `pandas` version. Check whether your pandas version is 1.x. If not, upgrade your `pandas` version.

`$ pip install pandas --upgrade`

Comment: Yes pandas was an old version. I upgraded to 1.0.3 but still same issue persists. While upgrading though I got some warning about pip version (currently in my system 19.0.3) - can this be the reason?

Comment: `pip` version is less likely to be the issue but you may still try. Ensure that the anaconda python environment you are using has the updated pandas. Using `pip install` sometimes installs the library in your local python env and not anaconda. You can do `conda install` instead. Also, what is your pandarallel version?

Comment: I tried all the upgrade options - upgrade pandas using conda install, pip upgrade, numpy upgrade, importing pickle. The issue persists. I have pandarallel 1.4.8 - it should be latest version as I just installed few days back. I am not an expert in python so was doing some google search and found a very relatable thread 
[link](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/2189) Not sure if it can help. As of now I will continue exploring the SGT package without multiprocessing.